# Multiple issues with Ajax login function due to browsers and cookies

Tags: login, cookies, authentication, browser-compatibility

Using basic usage of ajax login wordpress, no cookie wordpress_logged_in_ are created on safari and Chrome and firefox doesn't read user when cookie "wordpress_logged_in".

I have several subdomain that use same theme. I have configured wp-config to have all cookie defined on : ".website.com" . Domain and all subdomain get well same cookies.

```
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/wp-admin');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '.website.com');
define('COOKIEPATH', '.website.com');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '.website.com');
define('COOKIEHASH', md5('.website.com') );
```

I also added define ( 'FORCE_SSL_ADMIN' , true);

But I get only these cookies (each generated by `wp-admin` and `/wp-content/plugin`):

- wordpress_
- wordpress_sec_

**SAFARI :**
I don't have wordpress_logged_in_ cookie only on safari .
I have deleted all cache and cookies from safari browser but nothing helps.

**CHROME and FIREFOX :** I get well wordpress_logged_in_cookie.
But is_user_logged_in() return always "no". however I can access to wordpress dashboard with user logged in. But this function work for me (admin)

My php code :

```
function handle_user_login(){
    check_ajax_referer( 'ajax-login-nonce', 'security' );
    
    $log_param = isset($_REQUEST['log-param'])?trim($_REQUEST['log-param']):"";
    if($log_param == "login_data" ){
        $info = array();
        $info['user_login'] = $_POST['user_login'];
        $info['user_password'] = $_POST['user_pass'];
        $info['remember'] = true;
        $user = get_user_by( 'login', $info['user_login']);
        
          $user_signon = wp_signon( $info, false );
            if ( !is_wp_error($user_signon) ){

                clean_user_cache($user_signon->ID);                
                wp_set_current_user($user_signon->ID);
                wp_set_auth_cookie($user_signon->ID, true, is_ssl());
                update_user_caches($user_signon->ID);
                echo json_encode(array('status'=>1, 'message'=>__('Login successful, redirecting...')));
            }
        
    }
    wp_die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was due to bad use of COOKIEPATH.
The overwrite of COOKIE PATH blocked the browser to display and access to wordpress_logged_in_ cookie and its reading.
The browser Safari was entirely blocked and didn't allow access to wordpress dashboard.
Also the error "Cookie blocked : please activate cookies" of browser was entirely due to cookie.

My solution (work for domain and subdomain using same theme ):

```
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/wp-admin');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '.website.com');
define('COOKIEPATH', '/');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '.website.com');
define('COOKIEHASH', md5('website.com') );
```